# R changing column names containing plus or brackets

Tags: r, dataframe

I am saving my column names of a `data.frame` into a variable in `R`. Some of my columns names contain a plus sign `+`. `R` changes the `+` into a `.` when saving it into a variable. I would like to retain the `+` so that i can pick these columns again automatically when I need them.

Here is the command I am using to save the column names into a variable:

```
for (u in 1:50) {
    k <- colnames[u]
    f <- append(f,k)
}
## f is defined previously in my program
```

Here is the command I am using to get the names I need again:

```
file2 <- file1[,f]
```

**Example:** `column1+` is named `column1.` in the variable `f`

**Note:** This happened to the brackets `()` as well as slashes `/`

Any Ideas how I can get around this problem?

Comment: create the `data.frame` (or use `read.table`) with the option `check.names = FALSE`

Comment: This is not a comment... That's the ANSWER! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so the question remains answered. Set the option `check.names` to `FALSE` while reading the `data.frame` using `read.table` as:

```
read.table(file, check.names = FALSE)
```

**Note:** As @Roland says under the comments, it is better to keep the column names clean rather than using this parameter. You may also run into situations where certain functions automatically convert the names back. For example,

```
df <- data.frame('x+y' = 1:4, 'a+b' = 5:8, check.names = FALSE)
> df
#   x+y a+b
# 1   1   5
# 2   2   6
# 3   3   7
# 4   4   8

# Now adding a 3rd column, using `transform`
transform(df, c=9:12)
#   x.y a.b  c  # note that it reverts back
# 1   1   5  9
# 2   2   6 10
# 3   3   7 11
# 4   4   8 12

transform(df, c=9:12, check.names = FALSE)
#   x+y a+b
# 1   1   5
# 2   2   6
# 3   3   7
# 4   4   8
```

You'll have to know ALL functions that has `check.names=FALSE` and remember to use them correctly. This is at least one problem I could think of. Its rather better to have the columns without conflict.

Including operators such as `+` in column names can also interfer with the formula model interface:

```
dat <- data.frame('a+x'=c(1,2,3,4),b=c(2,4,6,8),check.names=FALSE)
lm(dat$b~dat$a+x)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found
```

You would need to use `lm(dat$b~dat[,'a+x'])`.

Comment: You should include a warning with this advice. It's generally better to sanitize column names.

Comment: May I ask why is it better to keep them clean rather than using them? there are thousands of columns, I don't think I will be able to edit them all. Thanks

Comment: Your answers are appreciated, I'll keep an eye on the functions i am using, Because the columns I have are like Column1+ and Column1 so it wont be easy to change anything. Cheers guys

Comment: If its okay for you, you can change everything to `names(df) <- paste0("V", 1:ncol(df))`

Comment: I am feeding the resulting column names into another program, so I want them exactly the same, they are even case sensitive. I think i'll keep on scanning the data frame between steps to make sure everything is alright. again... Thanks for your assist!

Comment: You would be better to do ``lm(b ~ `a+x`, data = dat)``